# Python get state district and state column for each lat long coordinate in Geopy

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis, geopy, nominatim

I have a list of 200+ latitude and longitude coordinate pairs.
For each coordinate pair I want to create a dataframe which contains column district and column state. So my dataframe will have 3 columns `cord, district and state`.

For this I am using geopy library but I am unable to get record for more than 115 coordinates.
**Sample Data**

```
    cord
0   (19.4, 17.93)
1   (55.54, 93.93)
2   (52.45, 78.93)
3   (65.54, 67.93)
4   (47.74, 99.93)
```

**Required Output Demo**

```
    cord        district    state
0   (19.4, 17.93)   xyz      aaa
1   (55.54, 93.93)  adc      aaa
2   (52.45, 78.93)  gyu      drt
3   (65.54, 67.93)  www      bhn
4   (47.74, 99.93)  ccf      bvg
```

I have tried this code but unable to get fetch details for more than 115 queries.

```
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
district = {} # Initialize empty dict
geo_loc # List containing all the codrinates in this format (lat, long)
for cord in geo_loc:
    geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent='user_agent')
    location = geolocator.reverse(cord, addressdetails=True)
    district[cord] = location.raw['address']['state_district']
```

> I need to fetch maximum of 500 unique coordinates at one time.
>
>  Also I need district and state name both in separate
> columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Nominatim Usage Policy](https://operations.osmfoundation.org/policies/nominatim/) they require not to do heavy usage i.e. maximum 1 request per second. "No heavy uses (an absolute maximum of 1 request per second)."
You can use geopy's RateLimiter to send 1 request per second.
I've tested the following code works for more than 115 requests:

```
from geopy.extra.rate_limiter import RateLimiter
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
import pandas as pd
geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="user_agent")
# add rate limit
reverse = RateLimiter(geolocator.reverse, min_delay_seconds=1)
state_list = [] # Initialize empty dict
# create dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({"geo_loc"  :[(19.4, 17.93), (55.54, 93.93),(52.45, 78.93),  (65.54, 67.93),  (47.74, 99.93) ]})
# get location coordinates
geo_loc  = df.geo_loc.values
for cord in geo_loc:
    # send request
    location = reverse(cord, addressdetails=True)
    # get state value
    state = location.raw["address"].get("state")
    # store state value
    state_list.append(state)
# assign back states
df['states'] = state_list
print(df)
```

Resulting dataframe:

```
        geo_loc                           states
0   (19.4, 17.93)                   Tibesti تيبستي
1  (55.54, 93.93)                Красноярский край
2  (52.45, 78.93)                   Алтайский край
3  (65.54, 67.93)  Ямало-Ненецкий автономный округ
4  (47.74, 99.93)                         Архангай
```